# Run java code for IBM Lotus Notes on Linux. Error no lsxbe

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I am trying to run a simple java code using Notes.jar to read from NSF files on Linux.

When i run the code, I get the below error

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lsxbe in java.library.path

This worked in windows when I installed Notes notes.

Sample JAVA Code

NotesThread.sinitThread();
Session s = NotesFactory.createSession();

I want the below to be fixed

1.Where to get linux software for lotus notes and how to install it

2. How to fix the below error
   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lsxbe in java.library.path

Answer (score 0):

Notes is only available on Windows and MAC. If you need to access notes data in linux, you have several options.
Notes Client on linux has been dropped around 9.0.1 FP6

a) Webservices.
b) NCSO.JAR and DIIOP see https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21994330

Comment: The third option is installation of a Domino server on Linux. It is still supported. You only need to set it up so that your code can access the APIs. It does not have to be a running server - but setting it up will require registering an ID file. You will have to talk to IBM about the license implications, if any, of doing this. Actually, maybe you'll have to talk to HCL about it. I'm not sure where the authority is at this stage in the transition process. Whoever your current license and support contract is through, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the old version of Lotus Notes Linux client or Domino server.
Then, you'll find the required files in the root folder of the installation.
I'll suggest you add the installation to the path variable (Apparantly, JVM doesn't always detect this values) or put the required files in usr/lib or /lib(Which is what we're doing). 
You'll require a few more libraries including liblxbe.so, 
I'll list them here  as libgsk8iccs_64.so, libxmlproc.so, libnotes.so, libndgts.so.
If you could find this files somewhere, you won't need the lotus client. Just the Notes.jar or NCSO.jar will work.

P.S.I'd very hard time figuring this out, so I'm listing other needed files also.